# flex-wrap: wrap not working on mobile iOS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, safari

I have this that works fine on my laptop, but not on mobile iOS.

```css
* {
  /* normalize */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  text-transform: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  background: 0 0;
  min-height: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

#a {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100);
}

#b {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px;
}

#c {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <ul id="c">
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>world</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>food</li>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>morning</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>beverage</li>
      <li>snack</li>
      <li>drink</li>
      <li>other</li>
      <li>world</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>food</li>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>morning</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>beverage</li>
      <li>snack</li>
      <li>drink</li>
      <li>other</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, on mobile it as *a few* rows, but mostly it overflows to the right. Like it will have 2 or 3 rows but then 15 or 20 items per row (when only 2 or 3 fit on screen). I haven't been able to get it working since I don't have a good system to debug on mobile.

Comment: What's your iOS version? According to the [compatibility sheet](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), iOS 3.2-6.1 Safari only supports old flexbox specs that completely lacks wrapping support.

Comment: try `max-width` or `flex-basis` instead of `width`. I've noticed Safari has problems with flexbox + width.

Comment: I have at least iOS 10

Comment: It's wrapping but it still goes over the edge before it wraps.

Comment: @LancePollard Please check my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for Safari on earlier iOS versions as well (10, 11) if you set flex to `1 1 auto` (short-hand for allow to grow, shrink, and set basis width automatically), and remove the `width: 100%` property from `li`. Tested on several devices running iOS 10 to 12. JSFiddle snippet available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/qvc6skfd/).

Updated CSS:

```
* {
  /* normalize */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  text-transform: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  background: 0 0;
  min-height: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

#a {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100);
  background: cyan;
}

#b {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

#c {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background: green;
}

li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
* {
  /* normalize */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  text-transform: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  background: 0 0;
  min-height: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

#a {
  display: flex;
  /* Use max-width for testing purposes */
  /*max-width: 25%;.*/
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100);
  background: cyan;
}

#b {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

#c {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background: green;
}

li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <ul id="c">
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>world</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>food</li>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>morning</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>beverage</li>
      <li>snack</li>
      <li>drink</li>
      <li>other</li>
      <li>world</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>food</li>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>morning</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>beverage</li>
      <li>snack</li>
      <li>drink</li>
      <li>other</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP Have you tried this approach? I tested it and confirmed to work on multiple iOS / Safari mobile versions so there should be no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

Update the style on li . Change `flex: 1;` to       `flex: 1 0 auto;` and remove `width: 100%`

```
li {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* width: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
* {
  /* normalize */
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  text-transform: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  background: 0 0;
  min-height: 0;
  user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

#a {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100);
}

#b {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 50px;
}

#c {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  /* width: 100%; */
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
    <ul id="c">
      <li>foo</li>
      <li>hello</li>
      <li>world</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>food</li>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>morning</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>beverage</li>
      <li>snack</li>
      <li>drink</li>
      <li>other</li>
      <li>world</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>food</li>
      <li>hi</li>
      <li>morning</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>beverage</li>
      <li>snack</li>
      <li>drink</li>
      <li>other</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hguq4pom/1/)

I tested it in iphone 6, IOS 10.3

Comment: Basically what you did was to copy my answer and change flex-shrink to 0. Do you think that was worthy of a new answer rather than a comment or edit?

Comment: Sorry to say but your answer was not working in the fiddle itself so i didnt bother to read it out completely! After i posted my answer i actually read what you had written and found out it was similar (but not exactly same) but because your was not working properly and mine was, i decided not to delete my answer.

Comment: I guarantee you [it is working](https://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/qvc6skfd) as I've tested it on multiple iOS devices and versions including iOS 10. Your answer is identical to mine except that flex-shrink is 0, which in this case will *not* be preferable as long-length text should be resized accordingly.

Comment: its not even working for me in ios 12. i have just checked your fiddle in answer jn my Safari. Let me take a screenshot and send it to you

Comment: [Try it on codepen instead](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EBWLpg) if you have a small iPhone screen as jsfiddle is badly unresponsive on mobile screens.

Comment: https://ibb.co/6vrxQMF check this screenshot of your fiddle on my ios12.2

Comment: sorry bt its not working for me in safari ios 12.2 so i do not consider it right